# Can I restrict access to specified packages in a github repository?

Tags: git, github, disclosure

If I have a git repo that has multiple packages that relate to some disclosed and some not disclosed products, is it possible to restrict access to the packages that have undisclosed data?

For example:

There are three full time employees and 2 contractors that can clone the repo so that they can debug and contribute to the code base, but the contractors aren't disclosed on unreleased product data while the full timers are.

I'd like the full timers to have full access to the repo but I want the contractors to be blocked from accessing the packages that have unreleased product data inside.

I've been fishing around in here, but not finding exactly what I am looking for:
https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations

Comment: By "packages", are you talking about directories or files inside a larger repo?

Comment: When you create a Java package, you are grouping together classes that belong together and giving them a unique namespace or name. This can help prevent naming conflicts with classes from other packages or libraries.

On the other hand, a directory is just a physical location on your computer's file system where you can store files. When working on a Java project in IntelliJ, you may create directories to organize your project's files, but these directories do not necessarily correspond to Java packages.

I am referring to packages, not directories.

Comment: OK, but how does that fit in with a repository structure? Do you have multiple packages within a single repository, or is there a one-to-one mapping of package to repo?

Comment: Sorry for late response... the repo is not yet created but currently planning how I am going to set it up.  I'll rephrase:  It is a multi module project, so multiple modules within the same repo.  I want to be able to control access on each module.

Answer (score 0):

Git read permissions apply to an entire repository at once. There's no effective way to allow users to read some things and not others; it's all or nothing.

Depending on your needs, you can take one of three approaches:

1. Two big repos: one for contractors and full-time employees, one for full-time employees only
2. One repo per package, with appropriate permissions
3. Some mix of #1 and #2

The second approach is a little more to manage, but it'll be much easier to adjust package permissions that way.